# Proving inequality in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I am new to measure theory and stuck at this problem.

> Let $1\leq p<\infty.$ Suppose that $f_k\in L^p(E)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x)$ converges almost everywhere on $E.$ Prove that $\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_{i}(x)\right\Vert_p\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\Vert f_i(x)\right\Vert_p.$

I don't know how to start this problem. Can anyone give me some idea? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a first step, if $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ can you prove that the function defined pointwise by $S(x) := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n(x)$ is in $L^p$?

Comment: You mean minkowski

Comment: Once you've handled snar's comment. consider that by the triangle inequality, $$\left \|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_{i}(x)\right\|_p \le \left\|f_1(x)\right\|_p + \left \|\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}f_{i}(x)\right \|_p$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Minkowski's inequality (i.e. the triangle inequality for the $L^p$-norm), we have

$$\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \right\|_p \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|_p \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \|f_i\|_p. \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, an application of Fatou's lemma shows that

$$\int \left| \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x) \right|^p \, \mu(dx) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int \left| \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) \right|^p \, \mu(dx),$$

and so

$$\left\| \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i \right\|_p \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \left\| \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \right\|_p.\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ proves the assertion.